# How does MySQL Auto Increment work?

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I was just creating a new table using MySQL Query Browser, and noticed there's a tick under Auto Increment Column. How does that work?

When adding to the database programatically, do I just add a number, and then the database automatically increments that number?

Everytime a NEW user registers on my site, I want their Customer ID (integer only) to auto increment, so I don't have to try and randomly generate a unique number.

Can this be done simply?

Thank you!

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanks! - So, I don't really need to do anything. It will just add a number whenever a new row is added? :)

Comment: I'd make this community for the newbies around here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> When adding to the database programatically, do I just add a number, and then the database automatically increments that number?

Yes, that's the way `auto_increment` works.

- The value will be incremented for each new row
- The value is unique, duplicates are not possible
- If a row is deleted, the `auto_increment` column of that row will not be re-assigned.
- The `auto_increment` value of the last inserted row can be accessed using the mySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but it *must* be called right after the insert query, in the same database connection

[mySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are not necessarily unique: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85e93/1

Answer (score 5):

1 more,
You can insert your own value also (ie your random value).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Auto_Increment columns work like they say on the tin. Tips

- when INSERT - ing, use NULL or omit the column
- Use LAST_INSERT_ID() (or API equivalents) to obtain the last generated value.
- for security and business logic reasons, it's usually better form to not directly use a key value for a customer identifier. Consider using Hashed / randomised surrogate customer keys instead.

Ta

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the exact purpose of `AUTO_INCREMENT`. It looks at whatever is the current increment value for that table, and stores that value plus 1 for the new row that comes in, automatically. You can omit that field from your `INSERT` statements and MySQL will handle it for you for every new row that comes in, giving each row its own unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable Auto Increment an ID will always get automatically added whenever a new record is made.. Example:

If you have 1 record with ID 1 in your table and you add a new record, the ID will automatically be 2.