# MySql - Deleting a row

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I've a table in MySql which includes user_id as First field. This field is a primary key and it is defined as Auto Incrementing. The problem is whenever I delete a row from the table by using the command,

```
delete from user where username="username"; //Username is the Second field
```

It gets deleted, but When I created a new Entry, the user_id is not adjusted by overwriting the deleted row.
Suppose I deleted the 3rd row in table which is the last row, then my new entry is created as user_id = 4 even the user_id = 3 doesn't exist now.

Is this how the Sqlworks works or should I have make changes in my query?

Comment: Its because the user_id is auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: This is by design. Auto_increment ids are designed to be only used once.

Comment: I think you need to do some research and some reading on how SQL works

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of the database on auto-incremented keys. If you want to reset the counter to some value you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/99557

Comment: yeah, maybe. Anyway thank for the clarifiacation guys. Have to do my further learning on how it works.

Comment: @mpcabd , that will very much use.. Thank you

Comment: You can check this link to see how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562479/how-does-mysql-auto-increment-work .

Comment: If you want change auto increment start Id alter table user AUTO_INCREMENT=3; But it raises some problem . The User Information mapped with another table means, The information will be conflict with another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to create another field so you have

```
id | user_id | username
```

`id` should be `auto_increment`

To insert you could count entrys in DB and raise the number +1.

Then you would have the result you want.

Of curse you could use id for this but in this case you allways have to reindex you user_id.

And actually thats not a way a primary key should be used.

**Example:**

Lets say you have a company with 100 customers. Today Customer 50 has customernumber 50 and tomorrow he has 48 because 2 other customers left your company. Makes no sence :D

Comment: Yes, That will become a conflict. My program is login and Registration which uses many tables and If I change my auto increment value, it'll become a whole mess.