# Where will the auto increment value be stored in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw multiple posts about getting the last auto increment value. But my question is Where will these autoincrement values stored in SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Why does it matter? That's dependent on the implementation of the DBMS, and has no relevance to anyone other than the developers of that DBMS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562479/how-does-mysql-auto-increment-work

Answer (score 1):

Actually auto increment value is managed by DBMS. You can just get IDENT_CURRENT and IDENT_INCR value by request to DBMS.

Like.
select IDENT_CURRENT('tblname') => get the current auto incremented record value

select IDENT_INCR('tblname') => get increment rate.